# How do I tag someone in Outlook but have their email address put in the cc?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, tags

I know that if I use `@John Smith` into the body of an email, then Outlook will automatically put John Smith's email address in the `To` field of the email.

**How can I tag John Smith in the body of an email but, for that one time, get Outlook to put his email address in the `Cc` field instead?**

*(My workaround is that I tag him as usual and then manually move him from `To` to `Cc`)*

Answer (score 0):

`@person` is **designed** to get someone's attention, and the entire Mention feature is dependant on them being in the `To` box.

The workaround you've described is a practical solution but would alter the behaviour when using the search facility to find Mentions.

[image]

An alternative would be to write an add-in, or find an existing add-in that performs the action you require.

For more, go [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-mentions-to-get-someone-s-attention-90701709-5dc1-41c7-aa48-b01d4a46e8c7).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is currently no such feature in Outlook client. As mentioned in the official documentation, the mentioned contact is also added to the To line of the email or the meeting invite.. Agreed here with @spikey_richie, which is intended to alert users who have been mentioned.

Many functions of Outlook are designed and upgraded according to customer feedback.  It is recommended that you could post the functions you expect and your sincere suggestions on [the website dedicated to collecting feedback](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/89a8afa3-2e1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).